# Sufficiency for convergence of a sequence $a_n$ satisfying a certain property

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

Let $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a bounded sequence of positive real numbers with the property that $$(a_n)^n \geq (a_k)^k \cdot (a_{n-k})^{n-k},$$
for all $n \geq 1$ and $1\leq k < n$. Is it necessarily the case that $a_n$ converges? For even $n$ we clearly have $a_n \geq a_{n/2}$ and thus the subsequence $a_{2^n}$ is increasing from which we can deduce that it does indeed converge. I haven't been able to either neatly prove that $a_n$ converges or find a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you include the $+\infty$ as a possible limit because otherwise something like $a_n = n$ easily gives a counterexample.

Now, fix $k$ and choose $n$ big enough. By repeatedly applying the inequality
$$(a_n)^n \ge (a_k)^k(a_{n-k})^{n-k}$$
we can get
$$(a_n)^n \ge (a_k)^{\left[\frac{n}{k}\right]k}(a_{n\, \mathrm{mod}\,  k})^{n\,  \mathrm{mod}\, k}$$
where $\left[\cdot\right]$ is the integer part. Thus 
$$\liminf_{n \to \infty}a_n \ge \liminf_{n \to \infty}(a_k)^{\left[\frac{n}{k}\right]\frac{k}{n}}(a_{n\, \mathrm{mod}\,  k})^{(n\,  \mathrm{mod}\, k)/n} = a_k$$
and so
$$\liminf_{n \to \infty}a_n \ge \limsup_{k \to \infty}a_k.$$

Comment: I don't include $\infty$ as a possible limit because I assumed the sequence to be bounded. Thank you for the answer. :)